# Kotlin compiler not found using Gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, kotlin

I'm trying to upgrade some Gradle projects from Kotlin 1.0.6 to its latest version (1.1.0). However, whenever it reaches the `compileKotlin` task it fails:

```
:kiwi-common-kotlin:compileKotlin FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':kiwi-common-kotlin:compileKotlin'.
> Could not find Kotlin Compiler jar. Please specify compileKotlin.compilerJarFile

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

The project itself is divided in a bunch of subprojects. To avoid dupes, we have a separate file with the Kotlin definitions and import it on the projects using it:

**File:** gradle/kotlin.gradle

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }

}

apply plugin: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions.jvmTarget = "1.6"
}
```

And we import it in the subprojects like this:

```
apply from: "$rootDir/gradle/kotlin.gradle"
```

Since we previously tried the early preview releases and it worked seamlessly, I changed the version a couple times to see in which version the plugin broke. It turns out it works up to 1.1-M03; beginning at 1.1-M04 it shows the exact same error as in the 1.1.0 release.

We're using Gradle 2.10 in the project. Can you help me figure out whether it is a problem in our configuration? or a known issue with the Kotlin plugin itself?

Comment: Will it work if you change `apply plugin: org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.plugin.KotlinPluginWrapper
` to `apply plugin: 'kotlin'`?

Comment: Also, it looks similar to this issue: [KT-16580](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16580)

Comment: @hotkey It won't work since this is a "shared" file that's being applied by the actual buildscripts. It's a known Gradle issue: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-apply-a-plugin-to-a-project-from-a-shared-applied-gradle-file/7508/2

Comment: @JoséCarlos I think hotkey is correct. The exact same configuration works in `kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.0.6`, so this isn't an issue with how the plugin is declared.

Comment: @CorayThan did you mean the issue or the apply call?

Comment: @JoséCarlos The issue. We already use `apply plugin: 'kotlin'` although via our own wrapper plugin to add KotlinLint.

Comment: The issue I mentioned above ([KT-16580](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-16580)) has been fixed in the 1.1.2 release. Could you please check that it works now?

Comment: @hotkey the plugin works as expected at 1.1.2. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out to be a bug with the Gradle plugin. As pointed out by hotkeys' comment, updating to v1.1.2 fixes it.